# Cordova Social Share Plugin on Ionic application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, share

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) to implement social share feature in my ionic App.

It works fine but sometimes it sends an empty picture.

This is my code

```
// social plugin to share
$scope.shareAnywhere = function(title, restaurantName, image, link) {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.share(title + " at " + restaurantName, "Check out this place", null, "https://www.xxxxx.com/post/" + link);
}
```

The main issue remains why is it not sending picture.

Comment: because you got no image defined

Comment: @RedzwanLatif what if I don't want an image, how do I write that ? I thought by putting null then there won't be an image

Comment: can you provide us the code with the image url?

Comment: @RedzwanLatif the image is 'var image=null' , I dont want to include an image

Comment: okay I understand that you dont want to include an image, but you stated that your problem is "it sends an empty picture". Please enlighten more on this

Comment: that's exactly what's happening, when I am setting the image as null. An empty white picture background is sent.

Comment: Oh I see, so this happens when you try to share it in facebook I suppose?

Comment: actually only on viber, the rest of the applications don't send an image

Comment: If its working as usual in other common social sharing app, there is a high probability it's probably a bug on that viber application itself.

Comment: oh okay, hmm yeah that makes sense! thank you :)